# How to get AWS AccessToken from Cognito, using Dev Authenticated Identities

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, aws-sts

I am using a Cognito Identity Pool with [Developer Authenticated Identities Authflow Setup](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/developer-authenticated-identities.html) - this auth flow was chosen because we are not able to use Cognito User Pools for some business reasons. Hence I implemented a *User Identity Provider Service* myself using API Gateway with an auth endpoint, which fires a Lambda function.

So I generated a temporary `AccessKey` and `SecretKey` by running
`cognitoidentity.getOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity` and afterwards `cognitoidentity.getCredentialsForIdentity` and got temporary AWS Credentials (temporary `AccessKey` and `SecretKey`).

Now I want to generate an `AccessToken` in order to authenticate my requests on AWS API Gateway on which I am using IAM authorization (so it needs an `AccessToken` to authorize requests).

My question is - how do I generate an `AccessToken`?

[image: AuthenticationResult contents]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to generate an AccessToken. Take a look at [the API Gateway IAM Auth docs](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/iam-authentication-api-gateway/):

> **Note**: To manually authenticate requests that are sent to API Gateway using another tool or environment, you must use the Signature Version 4 signing process. For more information, see [Signing Requests](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/api-reference/signing-requests/) in the API Gateway REST API Reference.

Following the link above, you'll see:

> Amazon API Gateway requires that you authenticate every request you send by signing the request. To sign a request, you calculate a digital signature [...]

Take a look also at this question, which is about doing the signing above: [Integrating an ID Pool with API Gateway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40777376/how-can-integrate-cognito-identity-pool-with-api-gateway)

I haven't done this myself, but I'd be very surprised if you had to do the above manually from the front-end. There should be a client you can use to handle signing for you, just like Postman does in the example in the AWS doc above. I.e. you give the client IAM credentials, and the client makes API requests when you ask it to, handling the signing auto-magically using the IAM credentials you provided. For example, [AWS Amplify seems to be able to do this for you](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-call-api-using-aws-amplify-javascript-library.html).

Comment: Hey, first of all thanks for your response, I asked this question because if you look at AmplifyJS framework auth steps you see that it returns AccessToken and IDToken (see image attached at my question). once you get an AccessToken you can authenticate requests on API Gateway with AWS_IAM auth attached. and it is simpler of course to pass an AccessToken in Authorization header as  `bearer ${AccessToken}` rather than signing requests.

Comment: I'm not sure that is accurate for you, since you're using dev-auth. I would assume the AccessToken in the docs comes from either a User Pool, or a 3rd-party auth provider integrated with ID pools. Since (correct me if I'm wrong) you're not using either of these, I would expect you need to access API Gateway using your IAM credentials (AccessKey and SecretKey), not an AccessToken